# postmessage return The data area passed to a system call is too small

Tags: winapi

i'm trying to send input to specific game using postmessage from win32api.  i already try many way to do this like pynput, pyautogui, pydirectinput, direct input using ctypes all of them are not working. only this show the error message. This is the code that i using for test it:

```
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con, win32api


def main():
    window_name = "SealOnline Plus Vibes       "
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
    win = win32ui.CreateWindowFromHandle(hwnd)

    win.PostMessage(win32con.WM_CHAR, ord(`A`), 0)
    win.PostMessage(win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_RETURN, 0)
    win.PostMessage(win32con.WM_KEYUP, win32con.VK_RETURN, 0)
    win.PostMessage(win32con.WM_CHAR, ord(`B`), 0)

    
def list_window_names():
    def winEnumHandler(hwnd, ctx):
        if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
            print(hex(hwnd), `"` + win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) + `"`)
    win32gui.EnumWindows(winEnumHandler, None)

def get_inner_windows(whndl):
    def callback(hwnd, hwnds):
        if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd) and win32gui.IsWindowEnabled(hwnd):
            hwnds[win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd)] = hwnd
        return True
    hwnds = {}
    win32gui.EnumChildWindows(whndl, callback, hwnds)
    return hwnds

main()
```

and it return like this

```
    win.PostMessage(win32con.WM_CHAR, ord(`A`), 0)
win32ui.error: CWnd::PostMessage failed - The data area passed to a system call is too small.
```

how do i fix it ?

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). In any case, you should not be getting an `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` error from sending a `WM_CHAR` message. There is no buffer to deal with.

Comment: But it only happens on specific game, i tried to another game it works..

Comment: Applications have several ways to observe input. Window messages are the highest-level way to do so.  Games, in particular, generally go with something much lower level, such as [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-raw-input), and ignore everything else (like window messages).

Comment: Is there any low level python library that could send raw input?